SAP PI/PO Outbound SFTP Not Disconnecting
Recently we have been having issues in PI/PO with outbound SFTP connection rejections due to having too many concurrent connections to the endpoint.
When this last occurred I attempted to restart the communication channel, but that didn't seem to drop the connections. I've also attempted to stop and start the Java Application com.sap.aii.adapter.sftp.app
The timeout on the communication channel looks to be 30000ms (30 seconds).
I'm having trouble finding if there is a spot I can check for active SFTP connections to determine how long they've been active for. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
